# MongoDB perl module: "query error: not authorized for query"

Tags: perl, mongodb

I am trying to loop through documents in a mongodb instance using Perl. The backbone of my code is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MongoDB;
use utf8;

my $client = MongoDB::MongoClient->new(
    host     => ...,
    port     => ...,
    db_name  => 'database_main',
    username => ...,
    password => ...
);
my $database = $client->get_database('database_main');
my $collection = $database->get_collection('collection');

my $query = $collection->find();

while (my $doc = $query->next){
    ...
}
```

However I get an error when the `find()` line is executed:

> query error: not authorized for query on database_main

I have tried doing exactly the same procedure using the Mongo shell and I get no error.

A. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

B. Does anyone know the circumstances this error is given?

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: Do you have authentication set up for this database? Are you calling the [authenticate](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB::MongoClient#authenticate-dbname-username-password-is_digest) method before querying?

Comment: @friedo When I initialise the $client within the "new( ... )" part I include my credential details. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Are you also setting the `db_name` parameter in your constructor? Connections need to be authenticated against a particular database. You can do that manually (with the `authenticate` method), or specify it in the constructor. Otherwise it will attempt to auth you against the `admin` database.

Comment: I do specify `db_name => 'database_main'` in the `new( ... )` constructor. So no need for a 'authenticate' method?

Comment: @Josh It might be helpful if editted your question to include everything inside `MongoDB::MongoClient->new( ... );`.  Obfuscating for security of course.

Comment: @Miller Thanks, iv done that

Comment: @Josh, hmmmm...if you have the `db_name` specified then it should call the `authenticate` method automatically upon connection. What happens if you call `authenticate` manually before trying your query?

Comment: @friedo I have just tried that and I still get the same error

Comment: @friedo do you know what circumstances this error is given?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the following version (the one that came with the unbuntu package 14.04 )

```
dpkg -l libmongodb-perlDesired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-==================================
ii  libmongodb-per 0.702.1+ds-1 amd64        Mongo Driver for Perl
```

which had version

```
version 0.702.1
```

I installed the latest version from CPAN, and it started wo
version v0.708.0.0